# Authorize a WordPress site and a React app with a web hook and token?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, wordpress, authentication, memberpress

Problem: The client is using MemberPress/Wordpress as their main platform. The users are being managed there. I built a React app to coexist with the Wordpress platform.

What I have done: Memberpress has webhooks. So when a user logs into WordPress I hook into that action with a node server that inserts the user into a custom database and I generate a token so that the user can access the nodes the user owns within my infrastructure.

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  const { id, email } = req.body.data;

  request(
    "https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/73289237283967",
    mutation,
    {
      wpId: id,
      email
    }
  ).then(data => {
    res.json({ status: "success" });
  });
};
```

The above gets triggered every time a user logs in. This executes a graphQl mutation that has a custom resolver that checks if the user with that `wpId` exists. If not it will create a new user. Then it generates a node token https://github.com/prisma-archive/graphcool-templates/blob/master/auth/email-password/src/signup.ts and sends back in the response.

Once I obtain the token I can make requests on the user.

Problem: I am not sure how I can connect the two. I have to redirect the user to the wordpress login page. The login action triggers the event, and a token will be generated. I am not sure how I can store that token in an efficient way that can then be sent back to my app.

My thought would be to write a small plugin inside WordPress to handle the response of the hook and store the token in local storage within WordPress. Then whenever the user clicks to go to the app I can put the token in the URL (feels slightly weird and cant directly go to the URL). I am out of any other thoughts and would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Does it sound like I am on the right track?

Comment: It sounds over engineered to me. Is there a particular reason you decided to add graphql ?

Comment: I was hired to build an app without knowing its role in the entire ecosystem of what the client wanted. I prefer this particular stack, so I made these decisions based on the information I had at the time. My fault really for jumping into this project without asking all the questions.